# JSON serialization & XML with attributes

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I have an array that needs to be serialized to either JSON or XML depending on the requested content type.

```
    $responseArray = [
                          "name" => ""
                        , "status" => -1
                        , "message" =>  "An unknown error has occurred."
                    ];
```

Encoding it with JSON works just fine

```
$plainTextResponse = $serializer->serialize($responseArray, 'json');

{"name":"","status":-1,"message":"An unknown error has occurred."}
```

Which is right and exactly what I need. The problem is representing it as XML

```
$plainTextResponse = $serializer->serialize($responseArray, 'xml');

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <name></name>
    <status>-1</status>
    <message>An unknown error has occurred.</message>
</response>
```

But intead of nesting those properties under command I need them to appear as attributes. That is doable this way (notice the @ before attribute names)

```
    $responseArray = [
                          "@name" => ""
                        , "@status" => -1
                        , "@message" =>  "An unknown error has occurred."
                     ];

...

    $plainTextResponse = $serializer->serialize($responseArray, 'xml');


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response name="" status="-1" message="An unknown error has occurred."/>
```

And obviously if I try to convert that to JSON then it will leave those @ in the names of the attributes

```
$plainTextResponse = $serializer->serialize($responseArray, 'json');

{"@name":"","@status":-1,"@message":"An unknown error has occurred."}
```

Is there a way to serialise an array so that it adds attributes in XML and does not have @ in json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create another array for xml serialization:

```
foreach($responseArray as $key => $value) {
    $respondeArrayXml["@".$key] = $value;
}
$plainTextResponseXML = $serializer->serialize($responseArrayXML, 'xml');
$plainTextResponseJSON = $serializer->serialize($responseArray, 'json');
```

Comment: That could actually work, shame I did not think about it! This solution is not that clean but does the job well. I have been looking into JMS Serializer as well but wow, the documentation is just close to non-existent

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with that!